# Zeoslib: How to tell when query execution is complete?

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, mysql-connector, zeos

I am using ZeosLib within Delphi to call a MySQL stored procedure through the TZQuery object. Immediately after MySQL finishes execution of the stored procedure I need to initiate my next block of code.

I added a `SELECT 1;` statement at the end of my MySQL stored procedure. What is the best way to find out that the results have been returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zeos lib does not play nice with stored procedures that return a result set.
It actively disables the returned resultset.
There is a workaround for that, you can activivate the resultset by altering the ZEOS source code.

However when you do that, you get lots of errors like `MySQL has gone away`.
At unpredictable times, which is probably why they disabled this option in the first place.

In the end the workaround I went for is to put any resultset that I need in a (temporary) table and query that after the stored procedure finishes. This solved the errors and works well for me.

Comment: That sounds strange ... I will expect two main reasons for that: 1) In the time of MySQL 5.0 SP itself were not stable. 2) The result set with BLOB may lead to "gone away". In any case we (da-soft) do not see such reports for long time already.

Comment: @da-soft, I hacked the source to force ZEOS lib to allow stored procedures to return a result set. That doesn't mean I did it correctly or that there is not other code that depends on stored procedures NOT returning a resultset.  The problem as I remember is that stored procedures already return a resultset indicating success or failure of the stored proc. Any other resultsets are additional, and this confuses ZEOS with is build on the assumption that the returned resultset will **only ever refer to success or failure**

Comment: @da-soft what do you mean by completion status? How do you check that?

Comment: @Johan When you say "query that after the stored procedure finishes"... How do you know when its finished?

Comment: There's an event that fires after the stored proc is done. Not sure which one. AfterApplyUpdates I think.